# Google Play Leaderboards instructions

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard

I want to add the leaderboard from Google into my application but I have a few problems.
Firstly, it seems to be necesarry to import BaseGameUtils into Eclipse, after searching all day long I still think that I did it wrong. I found everywhere a other solution but noone want to work.
Secondly, someone know any good examples about Google Game Services?  I just found some on Github but they arent helpfully, specially because mostly they have errors in the code.

Well, I hope you guys are able to help me, greets

Comment: Does noone have a sollution for this? I'm getting desperated :/

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that BaseGameUtils is required. The object was that BaseGameUtils and BaseGameActivity would provide some helpful functionality for your app- it provides some login and connectivity features that you would have to re-implement anyway.

As for using the leaderboard in Android, I think the google [doc](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards) in this case is not too horrible (assuming that you have otherwise configured your games' client appropriately, which should be doable by subclassing BaseGameActivity in your activity)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So that means that I can keep on without BaseGameUtils as library or something else? Cause on the google site you linked they wrote that I need to download the samples, which includes the BaseGameUtils folder.

Comment: No, you don't need the BaseGameUtils or BaseGameActivity classes. However, I wonder if at the end of the day, you would have to effectively write much of what is in there yourself anyway.

Comment: You don't **need** BaseGameUtils but it is definitely helpful to most developers.  As @RobDO'ConnellJr said, you will end up writing most of that again yourself.

BaseGameUtils is made for use with Android Studio, although the samples do have scripts to convert for Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I can acces Google Play now with my app. But if I'm in the ResultActivity, where the should be loaded to the leaderboard, the app crashes.
LogCat says that a fatal developer erorr has ocurred. What does that mean and how I can solve this?